# IIS7 Custom HttpModule for a Website - How to

Tags: httpmodule

i have been searching online for examples of how to create an HttpModule,
since i wanted to use one in a website i am developing atm.
all the examples i have found were pretty simple looking, but harder to implement then i though in the begining.

here is a sample HttpModule:

```
public class SampleModule : IHttpModule
{
    DateTime beginrequest;
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        // register for events created by the pipeline 
        app.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnBeginRequest);
        app.EndRequest += new EventHandler(this.OnEndRequest);
    }
    public void Dispose() { }
    public void OnBeginRequest(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        // obtain the time of the current request 
        beginrequest = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public void OnEndRequest(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        // get the time elapsed for the request 
        TimeSpan elapsedtime = DateTime.Now - beginrequest;
        // get access to application object and the context object 
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)o;
        HttpContext ctx = app.Context;
        // add header to HTTP response 
        ctx.Response.AppendHeader("ElapsedTime", elapsedtime.ToString());
    }
}
```

implementing the module should have been like so (by all the examples i have found):

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <httpModules> 
            <add name="TimeElapsedModule" type="SampleModules.SampleModule,SampleModules "/> 
        </httpModules> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

but this isnt right for IIS7! in IIS7 you should do:

```
  <system.webServer>
      <modules>
          <add name="TimeElapsedModule" type="SampleModules.SampleModule,SampleModules"/>
      </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

now, after figuring that out, i encountered another problem which i dont seem to find a solution for.
i am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'SampleModules' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

which is logical, since my module lives inside another class.
i would be happy if someone could help me solve this issue and i am hoping this post will help fellow programers on their day of need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out for the type I was using the namespace instead of the class name qualified with the namespace. In other words in my web.config I had

```
<add type="SampleModules.SampleModule,SampleModules" name="TimeElapsedModule" />
```

instead of

```
<add type="Test.SampleModules.SampleModule,App_Code" name="TimeElapsedModule" />
```